# Shell - Why would the built-in RANDOM function return 1?

Tags: bash, shell

Today, I find that my shell script occasionally exits early. After checking the code, I find out that it is because I have a `set -e` in the head of my shell script and I use the built-in function `RANDOM` to generate a random number.

With `set -e`, if any command in the script return non-zero, the script would exit immediately. So I write a snippet of testing code like this:

```
set -u
#set -e

for (( i=0; i < 100; i++ ))
do
index=$(expr ${RANDOM} % 16)
echo "RANDOM return $? , index is $index"
done
```

Pay attention to the commented `set -e`, I do that so as to show 100 output line, in which some `RANDOM return 1` really exists. For example, I get a result like this:

```
RANDOM return 0 , index is 2
RANDOM return 0 , index is 10
RANDOM return 1 , index is 0
RANDOM return 0 , index is 9
RANDOM return 0 , index is 5
RANDOM return 0 , index is 9
RANDOM return 0 , index is 4
RANDOM return 0 , index is 6
RANDOM return 0 , index is 2
RANDOM return 0 , index is 4
RANDOM return 0 , index is 14
RANDOM return 0 , index is 6
RANDOM return 0 , index is 2
RANDOM return 1 , index is 0
RANDOM return 0 , index is 1
RANDOM return 0 , index is 8
...(more line)
```

See? RANDOM returns 1 but it generates the random number correctly, and that is why my shell script exits early. After switching to python's random-number-generating code, my script is back to normal.

Why would `RANDOM` return 1?

Comment: Don't use `expr` for arithmetic; use `index=$(($RANDOM % 16))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$?` is the status of the last *command* you executed. `$RANDOM` is not a command, so evaluating it doesn't affect `$?`. (`$RANDOM` is a "shell parameter" or variable that yields a random integer between 0 and 32767 when it's evaluated.)

The `$?` value you're seeing is the result of executing the command `expr ${RANDOM} % 16`.

The `expr` command returns a status of `1` if the result of evaluating the expression is null or `0`, so you'll get a status of `1` whenever `$RANDOM % 16` is 0 (6.25% of the time).

```
% expr 1 % 16 ; echo "\$?=$?"
1
$?=0
% expr 0 % 16 ; echo "\$?=$?"
0
$?=1
```

If you've done `set -e` and you want to execute a command that might fail without terminating the shell, you can append something like `|| true`. Since the prefix to `||` is used as a condition, failure just makes the condition false.

```
index=$(expr ${RANDOM} % 16) || true
echo "Status of expr is $?, index is $index"
```